# What is this circular notification icon?

Tags: notification-bar, notification-icons

[image]

I have a Samsung J7 device and a notification logo showed up in my status bar as shown in the image. What kind of app is this? Thank you.

Comment: It was gone after a few minutes that is why I wasn't able to long press it.

Comment: It could just be the indicator for more than 3 or some number of app notifications. On my Samsung S9 w/Android 10, I have a dot in that location and I have more than 3 apps with notifications in the pull down drawer.